# "А именно" и название акта

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

«Данную проблему можно решить на уровне конкретного учебного заведения путем принятия им соответствующего локального нормативного акта, а именно(:) п(П)равил внутреннего распорядка».

Вопрос: 1. Нужно ли после «а именно» двоеточие?
2. Слово "правила" в данном случае со строчной или с заглавной? Ведь можно предположить, что это название акта? Хотя по сути этот акт еще не создан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Союз **а именно** в вашем случае присоединяет пояснительные члены предложения, после него двоеточие не нужно (см. в Правилах русской орфографии и пункутации под ред. Лопатина: *Недалеко от вас, а именно в деревне Пестрове, происходят прискорбные факты (Ч); Дом наш 
в Печатниковом расселили десять лет тому назад, а именно в шестьдесят восьмом году (Улиц.)*). Что касается нормативного акта, то логично написать его название с прописной буквы (руководствуюсь имеющейся в моем распоряжении Инструкцией по написанию отдельных наименований, слов и словосочетаний при подготовке проектов документов... ДСП).